# Jackson: serialize only a given instance variable of a given class

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Note that by serialization, I mean serializing to JSON (either a JsonNode, or the String representation of it).

This is Jackson 2.2.3. My class looks like this:

```
public final class Foo
{
    // the one and only instance variable
    private final List<Bar> l;

    // Allows deserialization with no problem at all
    @JsonCreator
    public Foo(final List<Bar> l)
    {
        this.l = ImmutableList.copyOf(l);
    }
}
```

I already know how to serialize all `Bar` instances (tested). Now I need to be able to serialize a `Foo` instance.

The only thing I have been able to do at the moment is to "decorate" `l` with a `@JsonSerialize` annotation but this gives:

```
{ "l": [ { "serializedForm": "of bar1"}, { "serializedForm": "of bar2"} ] }
```

And I want:

```
[ { "serializedForm": "of bar1"}, { "serializedForm": "of bar2"} ]
```

How do I achieve that? Note: I can use jackson-annotations

Note also that I can perfectly deserialize the second form to a valid, functional, `Foo` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
{ "l": [ { "serializedForm": "of bar1"}, { serializedForm": "of bar2"} ] }
```

is the correct serialization of

```
public final class Foo
{
    // the one and only instance variable
    private final List<Bar> l;
}
```

The JSON is a JSON object that contains a JSON array named `l` that contains two other JSON objects. From a Java perspective, this is also true. You have a a `Foo` object, which contains a `List` (corresponding to the JSON array) named `l`, that contains x `Bar` objects.

If you really want that JSON, annotate your field's getter with [`@JsonValue`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html). Read the javadoc carefully, because there are restrictions. For example

> At most one method of a Class can be annotated with this annotation;
>   if more than one is found, an exception may be thrown.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. I can perfectly deserialize a JSON array of Bar into a Foo. See [here](https://github.com/fge/json-patch/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jsonpatch/JsonPatch.java#L121).

Comment: @fge There's a workaround with `@JsonValue` on your field's getter.

Comment: OK, but the thing is, there is no getter for that field :/

Comment: @fge And you can't add one? I think it can be `private`.

Comment: Half there! I told only half of the story... But a private getter works. Thanks! Accepted